# Iterate through growing list and remembering position

Tags: c#, list, hashset

What I'm trying to do add an existing list from another class/thread (which is constantly growing) to a new list that contains values to be validated. But I'm not sure how to do this without processing the same values over and over. I would just like to process the newest added values. See below code

```
public static void ParsePhotos()
        {
            int tmprow = 0;
            string checkthis = "";

            List<String> PhotoCheck = new List<String>();

            while (Core.Hashtag.PhotoUrls.Count > Photocheck.Count)
                {

                    foreach (string photourl in Core.Hashtag.PhotoUrls)
                    {
                        PhotoCheck.Add(photourl);
                    }

                    checkthis = PhotoCheck[tmprow];

                    //validate checkthis here
                    
                    //add checkthis to new list if valid here

                    tmprow++;

                    while (Thread.Sleep(10000);

                };
           }
```

`HashSet<String>Core.Hashtag.PhotoUrls` is being updated every few seconds in another thread.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for a queue processor. I wouldn't continually add things to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no practical ways to do it that way, since `HashSet` is an unordered collections. Regular collections are also not thread safe, and should not be used without locking when using multiple threads.

A typical way to do it would be to use a concurrent queue, where the validation removes items from the queue, and adds them to another queue. The thread that produces the  items should be modified to add items to the concurrent queue instead of or in addition to the hashSet.

```
    public static Task ValidateOnWorkerThread<T>(
        BlockingCollection<T> queue, 
        Func<T, bool> validateMethod, 
        ConcurrentBag<T> validatedItems,
        CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        return Task.Run(ProcessInternal, cancel);
        void ProcessInternal()
        {
            foreach (var item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancel))
            {
                if (validateMethod(item))
                {
                    validatedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This also have the advantage of processing items in real time instead of needing to sleep all the time.